# Which code goes into which directory in a firefox add-on ? (Comparision with chrome extension files)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I read the documentation of SDK add-on development for firefox.

I have my add-on for chrome just built.I'm not sure of the terminology in firefox development.

**My files for my chrome extension:**

- popup.html, popup.js, popup.css, icon.png - files which deal with the pageaction popup in chrome
- contenscript.js -- which injects code into a page
- background.js - a background script for the extension
- manifest.json

1)So, what are the counter-parts for these files in firefox ?and , it seems firefox develpoment folder has

- data
- doc
- lib
- test
- readme.md

2)Do I need to use all of them ? What files go into what?

Comment: Im not sure about the coutnerparts but inside the resources folder you'll find lib and a folder named your addon name. In that you'll find main.js which is where all your typed js is. Data folder in the resource folder holds images and stuff you upload, contentScripts etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Lib: This is where you usually put your main addon code. By default, `./lib/main.js` is your entry point to the addon.
- Data: This is where you put content scripts. Content scripts function like running in a different environment and can communicate with your main addon code via message passing. Content scripts can be attached to a page ([Page-Mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)), in its own environment to perform a process or action ([PageWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker)), or be its own content (like a [Panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel)).
- Doc and Test are for documentation and tests; not necessary.

To translate it to chrome extensions, all of your pop-up code (js/css/html/png) would live in the ./data directory. Your main addon code would create a Panel (if I understand Chrome's "popups" correctly), and reference the code in data.

`background.js` IIRC is just a script that performs some process. Maybe some JS that performs some heavy-duty operation or is constantly scraping an API for updates, and runs independently of what tab is open. The SDK equivalent of that would be a PageWorker.

`manifest.json` is just the `package.json`.

Both panel and pageworkers use content scripts; for more info, [guides on working with content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides)

Comment: Wow! This is just what I wanted. Thanks once again @jsantell